# Converting svg to png generates blank image

Tags: php, image-processing, svg, png, imagick

I have went through a lot of similar questions.i couldn't find an answer to my problem.

I have an `svg` image. I'm trying to convert it into a png image.

I have been using a `300dpi` image as `background` of svg image.Now i have changed it into `600dpi`. After that `imagick` returns an empty png image.

```
            $svg=path to svg;               
            $im = new Imagick();
            $im->readImageBlob($svg);
            $im->setImageFormat("png32");
            $im->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
            $im->resizeImage(720, 445, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
            $base64=base64_encode($im);
            $im->clear();
            $im->destroy();
            return 'data:image/jpg;base64,' . $base64; //returns blank png
```

What am i missing here? Do i have to include any libraries??

> PHP VERSION: 7
>
> IMAGICK VERSION: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation of [`Imagick::readImageBlob`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimageblob.php)

> Reads image from a binary string

this seems not the correct method for reading from a file path.
You should either use [`Imagick::readImage`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimage.php)

> Reads image from filename

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImage($svg);
```

or the constructor [`Imagick::__construct`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.construct.php)

> ```
> Imagick::__construct ( mixed $files )
> ```
>
> Creates an Imagick instance for a specified image or set of images.

```
$im = new Imagick($svg);
```